Powerful functors and adjoints
I am trying to understand Street's proof Powerful Functors. In particular, proving that for a functor $p \colon E \to B$. The following are equivalent

the functor $p^* \colon \mathbf{Cat}/B \to \mathbf{Cat}/E$ has a right adjoint.
$p$ is a Conduche fibration

The beginning of the proof seems complicated. He uses coend calculus and later monadic functors. However, P. Johnstone uncomplicatedly (without coend calculus and monadic functors) showed that $(2) \implies (1)$.
I would like assistance with the intuition of coend calculus and monadic functors in relation to this. Perhaps a little bit of the explanation of the proof if possible.

Could you explain which part of the proof specifically you are having trouble understanding? I don't see any coend calculus, for instance, and Street gives a precise reference for the monadicity result he uses.

Where he defines the category $\mathbf{Mod}$ with composition as being a coend formula. He uses this for the rest of the proof.

Are you just asking for the definition of composition in Mod? You can find it on the nLab page for Prof, which is another name for that category.
